# Sum value from column A + B show in C

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have data in the database for column A, B and will show the total of A+B in column C. I have a problem where I don't know how to code the sum of A+B for all example: 200 data that I have in the database using LARAVEL

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | logins_sun | logins_mon |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |     587    |     347    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  2 |     527    |     147    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  3 |     589    |     347    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  4 |     557    |     147    |
+----+------------+------------+
|  5 |     547    |     247    |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: what you want to do after sum? do you want to save sum of A+b to another new column C. or just want to response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have table called `logins`, you can create a Model `Login` with following :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Login extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'logins';
}
```

And then do :

```
$records = Login::select(
    'logins_sun', 
    'logins_mon',
    \DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon as logins_sum')
)->get();
```

This will give you al rows in format:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | logins_sun | logins_mon | logins_sum |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |     587    |     347    |    934     |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

If you want to update :

```
\DB::table('logins)->update([
  'logins_sum' => \DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon')
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your response sir,i will try to implement your suggestion

Comment: I already follow your technique and get the 'logins_sum' value, but the problem is, the value didn't save in the database, I have tried to add ->save(); but it does not work, do u know how to make the login sum value save to the database?

Comment: I have  updated the answer to update all records with respective sum. Please check.

Comment: owh, this is the way to keep the record in the database. I'll remember it :) thank you, sir :) I will always remember your kindness :):)

Comment: `$records = Login::select(
    'logins_sun', 
    'logins_mon',
    \DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon as logins_sum')
)->get();`

Comment: and i add this code under the above code `$records = Login::select(\DB::table('logins)->update([
  'logins_sum' => \DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon')
]);` and I'm getting this error "syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'"

Comment: You do not need to add it inside select, you can directly do `\DB::table('logins)->update([
  'logins_sum' => \DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon')
]);`

Comment: works like a charm, thank you sir.. and I'm sorry for asking alot hehe.. I am a newbie in programming :D

Comment: haha Not a problem :) You can mark the answer as accepted if this helped you so the thread is closed

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('table_name')->selectRaw('logins_sun, logins_mon, (logins_sun + logins_mon) AS sum')->get();
```

might work. I'm kinda assuming logins_sun is column A, logins_mon is column B, and I created a new column C called sum.